# How can I see where how a file is being included in Xcode?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm running into an issue that I need to know how a file `common_headers.h` is being included, as various contents are accessible inside `some_implementation.cpp`. Inside `some_implementation.cpp`, I don't directly include `common_header.h`. Instead, I include `important_headers.h`, `old_headers.h`, `test_headers.h`, etc. One of these files *may* include `common_headers.h`, but more likely one (or more) includes a file that includes a file that includes `common_headers.h`. Is there a way in Xcode to see these paths?  Something like:

```
?> Find-Include-Path some_implementation.cpp common_headers.h
common_headers.h is included first via:
some_implementation.cpp
  important_headers.h
    deprecated_header.h
      common_headers.h
```

Comment: I don't know about xcode but if you're doing this simply for debugging purposes, include a macro in `common_headers.h` such as `#define COMMON_HEADERS_H` and then use `#ifdef` in your `.cpp` to check if it is included in the translation unit.

Comment: In this case, I know it *is* included; I just want to know from where

Comment: If so I think rob's answer should be right on the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to introduce an error into `common_headers.h`.  Put this at the top of the file:

```
#error where am I
```

Then choose Product > Build (default shortcut: <kbd>⌘B</kbd>).  The build will fail.  Choose View > Navigators > Show Issue Navigator (default shortcut: <kbd>⌘4</kbd>).  Open the disclosure triangles (option-click will toggle the entire tree open/closed) to find the full stack of inclusions:

[image: error include stack]

In my example, `ViewController.m` includes `ViewController.h`, which includes `important.h`, which includes `common.h`.

Comment: This is a good idea; unfortunately I don't own `common_headers.h`, but I think I have access to modify it for this one. Would prefer a less roundabout solution, but it seems practical - will give it a shot.